# Unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, vlc

While I was following a Raspberry Pi VLC hardware acceleration tutorial in the compiling stage I have received this error:

```
configure: error: Package 'libavcodec' requires 'libavutil =
53.3.0' but version of libavutil is 51.22.2. 
Pass --disable-avcodec to ignore this error.
```

I have tried to install packages I found on debian via dpkg, and then I started to receive these messages

```
root@bahaa-pi:/home/bahaa/Desktop/lib# apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
    libavcodec-dev : Depends: libavcodec55 (<= 6:10.2-99) but it is not installable or
    libavcodec-extra-55 (<= 6:10.2-99) but it is not installable

    Depends: libavcodec55 (>= 6:10.2-1) but it is not installable or
             libavcodec-extra-55 (>= 6:10.2-1) but it is not installable
    Depends: libavutil-dev (= 6:10.2-1) but 6:0.8.10-1+rpi1 is installed

libavformat-dev : Depends: libavcodec-dev (= 6:0.8.10-1+rpi1) but 6:10.2-1 is installed 

E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I've tried

```
root@bahaa-pi:/home/bahaa/Desktop/lib# apt-get install -f 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done 
Correcting dependencies... failed. 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  

libavcodec-dev : Depends: libavcodec55 (<= 6:10.2-99) but it is not installable or
    libavcodec-extra-55 (<= 6:10.2-99) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libavcodec55 (>= 6:10.2-1) but it is not installable or
                  libavcodec-extra-55 (>= 6:10.2-1) but it is not installable

Depends: libavutil-dev (= 6:10.2-1) but 6:0.8.10-1+rpi1 is installed 

libavformat-dev : Depends: libavcodec-dev (= 6:0.8.10-1+rpi1) but 6:10.2-1 is installed 

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. 

E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

What ever I try to do with `apt-get` I receive the same error. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Which distribution are you using?  You MUST NOT use Debian packages with Raspbian.

Comment: Agreed with joan. You can't use Debian packages on Raspbian, first off because they most likely won't be compatible (the packages you found on Debian probably coincide with your architecture - 32bit, 64bit - which won't match up to your Pi, which is ARM-based.) Second, even if you *do* manage to install packages from regular Debian on Raspbian, it may cause issues because of the fact that Raspbian, although based on Debian, is still a separate being and has its own software repositories.

Comment: i used .deb:armhf

Comment: Is that error is fixable ?

Comment: If it gets in the way of other dpkg installations, you could try `apt-get purge` on the packages flagged as having unmet dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no version of VLC which uses the GPU.

Use `omxplayer` which is already installed on the Pi and performs much better, because it uses the GPU. It is actually the core of the RASPBMC Media Centre.

NOTE `omxplayer` runs from the command line.

Comment: I saw it in other post after it was to late